# App to generate direct download links from a YouTube video

Tags: python, web-scraping, download, youtube, pytube

i need to make an program like this website: https://youtubemultidownloader.net/playlists.html

this website when you give it a playlist link it gives you a direct download link of each video in this playlist then you can use program like FDM to download it at once.

how can i do like this app?

i tried `pytube` library, to do it but the direct link doesn't have the information about the video title just the title it gives something like `videoback`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `playwright`. `Playwright` is a web scraping library that allows dynamic scraping of websites, and in many different browsers.

Install it in these two steps (in the terminal):

```
pip install playwright
playwright install
```

Then you can use it to web scrape, here's an example (in this case I used microsoft edge as my browser):

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(channel="msedge")
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('playlist link here')
    #find elements and get a list of the video titles
    browser.close()
```

Of course, you'll still have to find the elements and explore youtube's html structure to be able to scrape the page. Before doing anything however, I recommend checking out the [documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) so you have a good idea of what to expect and how to go about scraping using `playwright`.